# Is "I had the chance read him in his report, not all his report...." correct?

Tags: meaning, grammaticality, meaning-in-context

I have a full sentence: 
"I had the chance to read him in his reports, not all of his reports were perfect but his writing skill on a level far from I expected" 
Is this same with 
"I had the chance to read his reports, not all of his reports were perfect but his writing skill on a level far from I expected" 
I mean I know "read him" like understand about sb but I don't know the two sentences have the same meaning.

Comment: You are right that to _read somebody_ means to understand them, as in _I can't read him_. But if you read somebody their report (as in sentence 1), then it simply means you read the report aloud so that they can hear it. So, did you read the reports aloud to him or not?

Comment: I just edit the question, what about "read him in his report", @Shoe?

Comment: No, you should omit the _in_. Please note also that you should use a full-stop or semi-colon not a comma to separate the sentences; and that you need a verb in the clause starting _but his writing skill_.

Comment: and what about "read him in his reports" nearly same with "read his report" or same with "understand about him through his report"

Comment: Unfortunately, both of these sentences contain numerous grammatical errors, beyond just the difference you're asking about. _"I had the chance to read his reports. Not all of his reports were perfect, but his writing skill **is** on a level far from **what** 
I expected."_

Comment: Without knowing exactly what you want to express (see my first comment above), it is not possible to help you further.